# Wi-Fi connection timeouts on a specific MacBook

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport

Running OS X 10.10 Yosemite, and keep running into connection timeouts. Initially suspecting the home router or infrastructure issue, however all the other laptops in the house don't get any timeouts - so this must be something related to my own machine. I have no idea what that may be and how to diagnose and find the root cause. Perhaps it is a hardware issue with the Wi-Fi adapter? 
All the computers are using DHCP.

Will appreciate any suggestions.

Info:

Pinging the gateway results in timeouts of sometimes minutes.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2385 ttl=64 time=2.558 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2386 ttl=64 time=3.423 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2387
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2388
...
...
```

Pinging from another Mac at the same time shows no timeouts.

Comment: Have you tried deleting this network from your Preferred Networks list and recreating it? `System Preferences > Wifi > Advanced... > Preferred Networks`. Select the network (and any others you haven't used for a while) and click the negative sign. Then reconnect to the network you are having problems with.

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon. Just tried that per your suggestion. Problem still persists.

Comment: Are you running the latest released version of 10.10 (10.10.4)?

Comment: 10.10.3. Will upgrade to the latest and try again.

Comment: I restarted the machine before doing the upgrade and retested - problem seems to be gone! upgraded to 10.10.5 anyway and seems to still be running happily now. Hopefully this persists. Many thanks @IconDaemon !

Comment: if you want some background info on that: 10.10.3 used discoveryd for networking (which was horribly buggy and caused timeouts on network connections) but 10.10.4 went back to mDNSResponder and fixed a lot of networking issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was Discoveryd component in Yosemite which was causing the problem. Apple replaced the component with mDNSResponder in 10.10.4 which solved the issue. If you are running 10.10 to 10.10.3, you should upgrade immediately to 10.10.5 which is more stable with plenty of bug fixes.